# Convert struct field to string

Tags: go, struct, string-conversion

I'm trying to convert struct field "Category" to string so that I could do the concatenation in ConcatenateNotification.
Anybody knows how to do it?
Please, see my code snippet below.

```golang
//Category is enum of
//available notification types (semantic meaning of the notification)
type Category string

// Category allowed values
const (
    FlowFailure  Category = "flow_failure"
    WriterResult Category = "writer_result"
)

//Notification is struct containing all information about notification
type Notification struct {
    UserID     int
    Category   Category

}

//ConcatenateNotification loads data from Notification struct and concatenates them into one string, "\n" delimited
func ConcatenateNotification(n Notification) (msg string) {
    values := []string{}
    values = append(values, "UserID: " + strconv.Itoa(n.UserID))
    values = append(values, "Category: " + (n.Category)) // Anybody knows how to convert this value to string?

    msg = strings.Join(values, "\n")
    return msg
```

Comment: You might want to use `fmt.Sprintf("%v", n.Category)`. I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: @Giannis that's way overkill, `Category` is already a string type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Category` is already an underlying `string`, you can simply:

```
values = append(values, "Category: " + string(n.Category))
```

Comment: You are right Adrian. Your solution is more elegant. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you dont need strconv.Itoa to concat int with string, you can simply use `fmt.Sprintf("UserID:%v", n.UserID)`. You can use other verb instead of `%v`(more [here](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)) if necessary. And you can use the same approach with `Category`. `fmt.Sprintf` is kind of more idiomatic way to concatenate strings in go.

So the code will look something like:

```
//ConcatenateNotification loads data from Notification struct
// and concatenates them into one string, "\n" delimited
func ConcatenateNotification(n Notification) (msg string) {
    values := []string{}
    values = append(values, fmt.Sprintf("UserID: %v", n.UserID))
    values = append(values, fmt.Sprintf("Category: %v", n.Category))
    msg = strings.Join(values, "\n")
    return msg
}
```

If you want to shorten your code, you can also do something like:

```
func ConcatenateNotification(n Notification) (msg string) {
    return fmt.Sprintf("UserID: %v\nCategory:%v", n.UserID, n.Category)
}
```

Comment: "fmt.Sprintf is kind of more idiomatic way to concatenate strings in go" - not really. It's the more idiomatic way to *format* strings (hence the name). The idiomatic way to *concatenate* strings is with the concatenation operator `+`.